# Unable to publish views or routes into my project directories

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-nova

I just purchased a fresh Nova license and finished up with the installation. It's going all as expected besides some files/folders which I am unable to publish such as routes or views. There is a file(`login.blade.php`) stored inside the /nova directory which I want to modify the html/css but I am unable since the nova folder is stored inside the `.gitignore`. Also I want the routes as well to be published but no matter how much I searched there seems to be no answer. All help is appreciated